# Swift equivalent of C#'s IsAssignableFrom

Tags: swift, reflection

In C#, given two types, I can say something like

```
var stringType = typeof(string)
var intType = typeof(int)
var assignable = stringType.IsAssignableFrom(intType)
```

The value of `assignable` would be `false` since an `int` cannot be assigned to a `string`.

Is there any way to do this in Swift?

```
func isAssignable<T1, T2>(_ type1: T1.Type, from type2: T2.Type) -> Bool {
    // What's the implementation here?
}

let assignable = isAssignable(String.self, from: Int.self)
```

My suspicion is that this is not currently possible.

#### Why do I need this?

Some have asked why I need this. I've written a dependency resolution framework called [Guise](https://github.com/Prosumma/Guise). Each registration returns a unique `Key`. While it's actually unusual to use the `Key` for resolution—there are more elegant ways—there are times when it is useful, such as when resolving multiple registrations.

In the code below, look at the line that says `if type != key.type { continue }`. This just compares the reflected string representations of the registered types. It would be a lot more useful if instead I could test assignability directly, so that the generic parameter `T` would not have to be the specific type under which the registration was made. Something like `if !key.typeIsAssignableTo(type: T.self) { continue }`. Where `typeIsAssignableTo` is a thunk over the type in `Key`.

At this point I don't have an instance and don't want one. In fact, that's the whole point. Any good DR framework should resolve lazily, and this one does. I don't want to have to create an instance first before testing type compatibility.

```
public static func resolve<T, K: Sequence>(keys: K, parameter: Any = (), cached: Bool? = nil) -> [T] where K.Iterator.Element == Key {
    return lock.read {
        let type = String(reflecting: T.self)
        var resolutions = [T]()
        for (key, dependency) in registrations {
            if type != key.type { continue }
            if !keys.contains(key) { continue }
            resolutions.append(dependency.resolve(parameter: parameter, cached: cached))
        }
        return resolutions
    }
}
```

Probably clear as mud, but that's the best explanation I can give.

Comment: It would be interesting to know why you need such a function. In Swift you (almost) *never* can assign between different types, not even between integers of different size or between integers and floating point numbers.

Comment: Or is this about determining if one type is a subclass of the other (or a type conforming to a protocol)?

Comment: You could say `return type2 is T1.Type` – however that would only work for sub/superclass relationships, not for protocols (as `T1.Type` where `T1` is a protocol is `T1.Protocol` not `T1.Type`). Therefore it would probably be useless for whatever purpose you have in mind for it. There are also other compiler conversions that I doubt you can easily do checks for given only metatypes (e.g converting a `[Int]` to a `[Any]`).

Comment: @Hamish He might be asking for `as?` because that's how `IsAssignableFrom` is used in C#, an assignment guard.

Comment: @Sulthan I think he is really asking for a language wide `NSObject.isSubclass` class method -- a binary function, over two *metatypes*, that checks for relationship between the specified types.

Comment: @MartinR: I'd like this for my dependency resolution framework, called [Guise](https://github.com/Prosumma/Guise/tree/hashable). It would help me handle an edge case, but it's too complex to explain here in a StackOverflow comment.

Comment: @MartinR: And yes, it is about determining if one type is a subclass of another or conforms to a protocol. And I need to know without having any instances of those types.

Comment: @Sulthan: The problem with `as?` is that it requires an instance. I want to test assignability of instances given their types, but without actually having the instances handy. As I said to @MartinR, this would be useful in my dependency resolution framework, [Guise](https://github.com/Prosumma/Guise/tree/hashable).

Answer (score 0):

Try this function from `NSObject`:

```
class func isSubclass(of aClass: Swift.AnyClass) -> Bool
```

For instance:

```
UILabel.self.isSubclass(of: UIView.self) // true
UIView.self.isSubclass(of: UILabel.self) // false
UIView.self.isSubclass(of: UIView.self)  // true
```

**PS**. This method is from the `NSObject` class so this only works within its subtypes.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this method and it's not what I want. I need something that works with any type, including non-Objective-C types.

Answer (score -2):

Not exactly, if you tried to construct an object from another and it was not compatible the Swift way would be to return nil.
So you could have your scenario like so:

let assignable = Int(text: stringElement)

In this case, you would have an optional Int, because there is a chance that a string may not be convertible to an int.

Comment: You're talking about instances here, but in my case, I have two known types but no instances of those types. In fact, if I have to create instances of these types, it defeats the purpose for which I want to use this feature.